# keep text formatting when copying and pasting in/from memo

Tags: lazarus

Basically, i paste my text in a memo, push some buttons and it's edited. That's what it should do. But when i copy my end-text out of it and paste it in a website, the text looses all of its line breaks. I tried adding them but that does not help, i tried richmemo, richedit. Nothing works.

Comment: Paste it into which website?  Push what buttons?  Format the text how? Did you try pasting into Notepad?  I'm guessing that the problem is the website.  Text in a `TMemo` retains formatting when copied.  Otherwise, you need to provide enough information to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Which platform do you work on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem. It was wordwrap. Had to divide the memo lines in strings to achieve it but it came out just fine.